# Windows Forms comboboxes are automatically synchronized; why?

Tags: winforms, combobox, dataset

In VS 2010, I created a data-bound form, by dragging from data source window to an empty form. Data source (typed dataset) has two columns: CustomerCode and CustomerName. In the form's Load event I wrote:

```
private void SalesInvoiceForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Populate customer code combobox
  var customerTableAdapter = new companyDataSetTableAdapters.CustomerTableAdapter();
  customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.companyDataSet.Customer);
  customerCodeComboBox.DataSource = this.companyDataSet.Customer;
  customerCodeComboBox.ValueMember = "Code";
  customerCodeComboBox.DisplayMember = "Code";

  //Populate customer name combobox
  //customerNameComboBox.DataSource = this.companyDataSet.Customer;
  customerNameComboBox.ValueMember = "Name";
  customerNameComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";


  this.salesInvoiceTableAdapter.Fill(this.companyDataSet.SalesInvoice);
}
```

Somehow, when I select customer code from customerCodeComboBox, customerNameComboBox is automatically synchronized, i.e, selected customer's name is shown. The same is true for customerNameComboBox. Initially I thought I needed a code for each combobox's SelectedIndexChanged event hanlder, two synchronize both of them. Why this is happening automatically? Because their DataSource property is set to the same datatable? I thought datatable doesn't have any position related feature.

Answer (score 0):

> Why this is happening automatically? Because their DataSource property is set to the same datatable?

Yes

> I thought datatable doesn't have any position related feature.

It doesn't; but the binding system uses a [`CurrencyManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.currencymanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) behind the scenes, which handles the notion of current item.

Comment: The form doesn't have customerBindingSource, however. It has salesInvoiceBindingSource though. Also, I noticed that the same doesn't work for comboxboxes inside DataGridView. Could you explain that?